# Calculating Geometric Mean in Raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am calculating Geometric Mean for land degradation mapping. I am applying following formula in ArcGIS 10.2- 
`("GW.img" * "LULC.img" * "Rain.img" * "Temp.img" * "Wind.img" * "NDVI.img" * "Livestock.img" * "Pop_Density.img" * "USLE" * "WEQ.img") ** (1/10.)`
on the raster calculator. The final result is ranging from 4.1 to 8.5. But this map having various blank patches with no value. I am quite dubious about the way i am applying formula in raster calculator. Please, suggest me the right way to do it.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: **ArcGIS 10.2**

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In a repeated attempt, Now I got a final map, which result is ranging from 4.1 to 8.5. But this map having various blank patches with no value. I am quite dubious about formula which I have used for Geometric mean calculation.

Comment: If you are dubious about the formula then where did it come from?

Comment: @PolyGeo. I mean to say, what is the appropriate way of applying Geometric mean formula of  [(X1,X2....Xn)^1/n] in raster calculator.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to improve it with such clarifications at any time.

Comment: a) see if any raster stores negative value (e.g. temp) b) Use Power(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have `NoData` or `Null` values in one or more of your input rasters.

As described in the Esri help page [*NoData and how it affects analysis*](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/nodata-and-how-it-affects-analysis.htm), the presence of a `NoData` value in **any** of the input rasters can result in `NoData` in the output raster for some operators. This is definitely the case for the [multiply/times map algebra operator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/arithmetic-times-operator.htm), as shown below:

[image]

If my hunch is right, you will want to use the `con()` and `isnull()` map algebra operators to properly fill in the `NoData` values, as described in this GIS.SE question: [*Dealing with NoData in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8387/dealing-with-nodata-in-arcgis-spatial-analyst).